# Making a phone call with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mobile

I know that `<a href="tel:+15555555555">1-555-555-5555</a>` will launch the dialer on a phone and will cause FF and Chrome to try and launch the default dialer on a traditional computer; however, I need to execute some JavaScript prior to the default behavior being launched to implement some tagging (specifically dcsMultiTrack). I've tried the following, but it isn't making the phone call, instead it just sits.

```
<a href="tel:+15555555555" class="call_now preventPhone" onclick="trackPhone('SomeEvent', 'SomeTag','tel:+15555555555',this)">1-555-555-5555</a>


function setLocation(nextPage, target) {
    if (target == "_blank") {
        window.open(nextPage);
    }
    else {
        location.href = nextPage;
    }
}
function trackPhone(vPageUrl, vPageTitle, phone, aTag) {
    dcsMultiTrack('DCS.dcsuri', vPageUrl, 'WT.ti', vPageTitle);
    setTimeout("setLocation('" + phone + "', '" + aTag.target + "')", 500);
    return false;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.preventPhone').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

EDIT:

To clarify, I'm preventing default because the phone call action is firing too quickly for dcsMultiTrack to return its callback, which is why I'm hoping there's a JS equivalent for tel:+....

Comment: Try not returning `false` from the `trackPhone` method.

Comment: You're *specifically* preventing the default handling. Why are you doing that if you want default handling once your script is done?

Comment: the phone call action is firing too quickly. With a normal link this works just fine. To clarify, I'm hoping there's a way to mimic tel:+.... with JavaScript, but Google isn't being very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call the function preventDefault()? if it is called, the default action of the event(launch the default dialer on a traditional computer) will not be triggered. See [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: You would have to call the default event yourself later in the method after unbinding.

Ex: 

 '$('.preventPhone').click( function(ev){

         ev.preventDefault();
         // ... put Your code here
         //later you decide you want to trigger the default event
         $(this).unbind('click').click();
  });'
of course you have to delete the 'onclick=""' from your html tag, hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

While I was looking for dcsMultiTrack solutions, I stumbled upon this post and I believe I have a solution for you.

First, create your tag dynamically, so that you can manipulate it later.

```
var myLink = document.createElement('a');
myLink.setAttribute('id','myPhoneLink');
myLink.setAttribute('href','javascript://');
var myTextNode = document.createTextNode('1-555-555-5555');
myLink.appendChild(myTextNode);
```

Basically this creates a link that does nothing when it is clicked.

Within your function, you can change the value of the attribute href:

```
myLink.setAttribute('href','tel:+15555555555');
```

Now, your link works. You could have this one line in a separate function that has a conditional statement like this:

```
var myCheckFunc = function(){
    if(condition){
      myLink.setAttribute('href','tel:+15555555555');
    }else{
        myCheckFunc();
    }
```

This way your function is calls itself until the condition is met, which changes the href of your link when you are ready for it to change.

Now, I have a question that I will posting concerning webtrends and if you could help me configure the admin, then I would be grateful.

When a banner is clicked, the following function is called

```
 dcsMultiTrack('DCSext.Carousel','Home','WT.ti','Home',
 'WT.pc','Banner;Position','WT.pn_sku',tempPC,'WT.tx_u',
 tempQuantity,'WT.tx_s',tempQuantity);
```

How do I setup a report to that will show the results in a three column report, showing the Carousel is HOME, the Banner and Position?